# Selenium c# How to stop the . exe file after the test was excuted

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have test script which runs the .exe file (Handles my windows authentication) and when the test was executed i quit the driver ( which means close the browser and kills the .exe files) but it doesn't work

The .exe file :

```
Process.Start("c:\\AutoIT\WindowshandleAuthentication.exe")
```

Quit the driver

```
driver.quit();
```

It doesn't stop the .exe running.

I wanted to close the browser and the .exe file at the same time . Any solutions?

Comment: I think you'll need to kill the process: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.kill?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Is "WindowshandleAuthentication.exe" an application you created?
If so, you could modify it so that if it receives a keystroke, it closes.
Then after calling "driver.quit()," send a keystroke to "WindowshandleAuthentication.exe"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Start WindowshandleAuthentication.
Process process = Process.Start("WindowshandleAuthentication.exe");
// Wait one second.
Thread.Sleep(1000);
// End WindowshandleAuthentication.
process.Kill();
```